# Resolve URL Contents Into HTML Head As Text

Tags: javascript, html

I created a plugin for some web software that doesn't natively support plugins. I found that I could inject code into the head of the plugin webpage through their GUI. Currently, users have to paste a huge block of code into the head which contains the plugin HTML, CSS, and JS all minified into one block. I'd like to instead serve this over a CDN so users could simply subscribe and receive all updates without having to repaste. It also would keep them from having to paste a large chunk of code into the tool and instead it would be a nice link.

I tried:

```
<link rel="import" href="~my_CDN_link~">
```

but it seemed to only partially work. I didn't really understand the issue, but I saw that import is deprecated so this seems like it would only be a temporary patch.

At the end of the CDN link is a text file which contains:

```
HTML
<script>~my_scripts~</script>
<style>~my_styles~</style>
```

I was hoping there is some way to just resolve this link into the text which it contains and "paste" it into the head of the document. Maybe this isn't even the approach I should be taking? Should I instead provide two links? One for the stylesheet and one from the JavaScript? The JavaScript could then make a call to get the required markup and append it to the document. I'd love to keep it as one link if at all possible.

Comment: I'd personally inject one Javascript file reference, and have that do all the further injection you need.  I've done this before as a way to share scripts that modify websites on the fly, simply by clicking a bookmarklet.

Comment: It's not very clear what you try to achieve

Comment: @Supersharp, the solution was to do what Archer had recommended. I wanted to serve HTML, CSS, and JavaScript all from a single CDN link. The solution was to bundle it all within the JavaScript and serve just that script from the CDN. On page load, the script injects the HTML and CSS and goes to work with everything else.